# virtual keyword internals

Tags: c++

I heard lots of times virtual function is usually implemented using a vtable. But I actually don't know actually how its implemented and how it works.

*edit*

I didn't actually get this code: How can it be rewritten. Can someone explain this in detail please.

Finally, let's see how the compiler implements a call to a virtual function. Your code might look like this:

```
 // Your original C++ code

 void mycode(Base* p)
 {
   p->virt3();
 }
```

The compiler has no idea whether this is going to call `Base::virt3()` or `Der::virt3()` or perhaps the `virt3()` method of another derived class that doesn't even exist yet. It only knows for sure that you are calling `virt3()` which happens to be the function in slot #3 of the v-table. It rewrites that call into something like this:

```
 // Pseudo-code that the compiler generates from your C++

 void mycode(Base* p)
 {
   p->__vptr[3](p);
 }
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vtable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common implementation is to have one pointer at the beginning of every instance of an object that points to a vtable. There is one vtable per class, so if you have a class A and class B, there will be one table for each.

The vtable essentially has a bunch of function pointers, so if class A has two virtual functions, foo() and bar(), the table will have pointers to both. If class B overrides those two functions, it will have its versions of foo() and bar() at the same offsets.

Answer (score 4):

The explanation of the [internals of virtual functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.4) on the C++ FAQ is pretty good. You should give it a read. I think it would be better if you tried to understand it yourself and then asked your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to understand how vtables work is to implement the same type of functionality in C using function pointers because all that a vtable is,is a table of function pointers to the concrete implementations.